# How do I get nth number of records from 100 records by select query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to select nth record randomly from 100 of records by using select query in SQL Server

Comment: Isn't picking the Nth number equivalent to picking the first if random order is used?!

Comment: Remember to select answers to your questions. Thats how you get people to help you more often. Plus you get points for it!

Answer (score 2):

In the below code `@R` produces the random number and it is used by the CTE to pick the random row.

```
DECLARE @Upper INT;
DECLARE @Lower INT;
SET @Lower = 1   
SET @Upper = 100


DECLARE @R INT = (SELECT @Lower + CONVERT(INT, (@Upper-@Lower+1)*RAND()))  

;WITH myTableWithRows AS (
            SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY myTable.SomeField)) as row,*
            FROM myTable)
        SELECT * FROM myTableWithRows WHERE row = @R
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-query solution:

```
select top 1 t.*
from table t
order by newid();
```